# 0x is getting inserted into database while passing a file using web api

Tags: c#, sql-server, webapi

```
ALTER PROCEDURE INSERT_PDF
    @DOCUMENT VARBINARY(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PDF
           (Document)
     VALUES
           (@DOCUMENT)
END
GO

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace pdf.Controllers
{
    public class pdfController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("insertPdf")]
        public int insertReceiptDocument(MemoryStream fileToPut)
        {
            //int varID = 0;
            fileToPut = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] document = fileToPut.ToArray();
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERPConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            //DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT_PDF";
            sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@DOCUMENT", SqlDbType.VarBinary, document.Length).Value = document;
            myConnection.Open();
            int rowInserted = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

0x is getting inserted into the database, when passing a file in postman using web api. Wanted to insert the binary data of a selected file into the database. Therefore, how to insert a pdf file in the form of binary data into the database in web api?

Comment: I do not thing the 0x is actually getting inserted.  Since data is binary the database viewer is just showing the 0x and is not part of the data.

Comment: When SQL Server shows you the contents of a table, it obviously has to convert everything into strings first, and varbinary literal strings are always of the form `0x<more hex>`. So *where were you looking* to see this issue and is it an *actual problem* or just a product of how you're checking?

Comment: Pretty sure it is loading an empty binary array into the DB because you are wiping out the contents of fileToPut by setting it to a new MemoryStream().

Answer (score 0):

You're disposing of the binary data before you even use it. In your method above, remove the following line of code:

```
fileToPut = new MemoryStream();
```

That line of code erases the value that is received from in the `fileToPut` parameter, so you end up inserting no binary data into the database.

Comment: After removing that line of code, I'm getting an error named System.NullReferenceException.

Comment: What is `null`? Is it `fileToPut`? If so, then it's null before it is passed into the `insertReceiptDocument()` method. Have you used the debugger? Put a breakpoint in the code and figure out what is `null`. And/or refer to the exception stack trace to determine the line of code the `NullReferenceException` occurs on.